# How to modify uitable cell color according to data in table (in Matlab)?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-uitable

I have a matlab function that returns results in a uitable.

There are 2 columns and lots of rows to the table: first column is "values" and second column is a "safety threshold/confidence interval" of sorts.

I'd like to format the output so that certain cells get painted red:
those for which the "value" in column 1 exceeds the corresponding "safety threshold" in column 2.

Is there a way to do this using just Matlab?

PS:
I am aware of the following page:

http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/150507

but it seems like a lot of tinkering to me, and I'm hoping that since that post was made, maybe Matlab has caught up and brought this functionality built in?

Comment: not sure why you *wouldn't* want to use Yair's code. I don't believe this functionality is available naively, although I could be wrong; Yair has an entire blog about doing things in MATLAB that you can't naively. It is surely a hack and dependent on undocumented features, but that's the code I would use.

Comment: there's also this recent blog post by Yair Altman: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/uitable-customization-report/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you read the discussion [carefully](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/150507#676085), you'll find out that [UITABLE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uitable.html) supports HTML content...

Here is an example:

```
X = rand(100,2);

%# convert matrix of numbers to cell array of strings (right aligned)
XX = reshape(strtrim(cellstr(num2str(X(:)))), size(X));

%# find cells matching condition
idx = ( X(:,1) > X(:,2) );

%# use HTML to style these cells
XX(idx,1) = strcat(...
    '<html><span style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;">', ...
    XX(idx,1), ...
    '</span></html>');

%# create table
f = figure;
h = uitable('Parent',f, 'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0.05 0.05 0.9 0.9]);

%# set table data
set(h, 'Data',XX)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: in fact, there is no need to close the HTML tags (</span></html>)

Comment: For anyone interested, I posted a dedicated (expanded) article about this issue on my website: http://UndocumentedMatlab.com/blog/uitable-cell-colors/

Comment: definitely worth reading, thanks again Yair. Perhaps you can post an answer here with a small example showing the "cell renderer" method. You will certainly get my vote :)

Comment: Amro - thanks for the kind words. I did post an answer with this link back in 2011 but it was deleted for being "self-promotional" and "nothing but a click-through link". When [I asked about it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183308/answer-deleted-by-a-moderator-reconsideration) I got tons of cold water poured over my head, so it kind of blew the wind from my sails, so to speak...

Comment: @YairAltman: sorry you had a bad experience. Your article is definitely on topic and solves the issue at hand. But I guess it would have been more agreeable with the ways of Stack Overflow if you had included a summary in addition to the link, that way the answer is self-contained (you could makes the changes and vote to undelete if you still want to)... Anyway, let me just say that your contributions in MATLAB community are always appreciated

Comment: @Amro: Using this `XX(idx,1) = strcat(...
    '<html><span style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;">', ...
    XX(idx,1), ...
    '</span></html>');` in my code produces some kind of weird symbols. My data `XX` is a cell array..

Comment: @Pupil: I have no way of knowing what your code is doing, but I suspect that your cell array contains numeric data not strings (i.e `1` not `'1'`). If that's not it, please create a new question and post the needed info...

Comment: @Amro: I have created a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527842/matlab-weird-symbols-on-on-coloring-specific-cell-data-in-uitable) based on above query. Thanks!

Comment: I posted an answer there. As I suspected, you have numeric values instead of all strings. That's the reason why I used NUM2STR in the example shown above