# Matlab / GUI / matrix

Tags: matlab, events, user-interface, handle, matlab-guide

I have to built GUI in matlab and main part of it is matrix like in 'Saper' game.
Its matrix 10x10 and if user press one of ex. A(1,1)  then this part has to change color and value from 0 in A(1,1) has to change to 1.

How can I do that ?

I don't know where to start.
I have experience in matlab programin but not with GUI.

Ok. Now I now that is better to use uitable.

```
A = [1 1 1 ; 0 1 0 ; 0 0 1]; //example matrix 3x3

t = uitable;

set(t,'Data',A);
```

Question now is how to get access to specific element for example

```
 If( click on element A(1,1) )
{
  do sthing
}
```

I know that there is sth like ***CellSelectionCallback***
but really have no idea how to use it.

Comment: You said if A(1,1) is 0, then it must change to 1. What if originally it is 1, should we change to it 0 or something else after pressing?

Comment: The change(s) must be on pressing on A(1,1) only or on pressing on other cells too in that table? Would you be okay if there is no color change to any cell in the table, and we only change the values? Please make your requirements clear.

Comment: A(1,1) was example u can change color by pressing in every cells

Comment: If you would like to change colors on cell by cell basis in a table, I don't think would work or if it has to, would be hard work. In that case, pushbuttons would be the only option.

Comment: If you want to persist with table, try these two links - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409766/how-to-modify-uitable-cell-color-according-to-data-in-table-in-matlab and http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/uitable-cell-colors/

Answer (score 0):

Pointers to get you home -

- Create a matrix of 10x10 pushbuttons corresponding to 10x10 matrix 
  data using MATLAB GUI GUIDE. More info - http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/gui-building-basics.html
- In each pushbutton callback function, use something like this –
  set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','red'); and change corresponding value 
  of the specific element in A.
- For saving and retrieving your data matrix, you would need to learn [data sharing among different GUI components](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/creating_guis/sharing-data-among-a-guis-callbacks.html).

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about using table instead of 100 buttons. But mayby u know how to get access to specific row/column in cell when I pressed

Comment: I would advise TABLE instead of pushbuttons spread all over the GUI - http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/uitable.html

Comment: Any advise hot to get acess to specific element

Comment: This must get you all the info - http://www.mathworks.in/products/matlab/examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/matlab/uitabledemo.html