# Pointing on specific cell in uitable of Matlab from the code

Tags: matlab-uitable

Does somebody know, how to point on specific cell in uitable of Matlab from the code (like it's done for listbox: set(handles.listbox1, 'Value', 25) - pointing on row 25 of listbox) ?

Comment: May help: [How to modify uitable cell color according to data in table (in Matlab)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409766/how-to-modify-uitable-cell-color-according-to-data-in-table-in-matlab).